# Add QWidget within containing QWidget at coordinates relative to the containing QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

Note: when I say parent or child in this question, I'm talking about having QWidgets within QWidgets rather than class inheritance.

Suppose I have a QWidget `parent` within some layout in my application. I need to insert another QWidget `child` within `parent` at a point relative to the position of `parent`. I need for the position of `child` to change as the position of `parent` changes.

In this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOkJe.png), the yellow box is a window. The green box is the `parent` widget, and the blue and magenta boxes are some `child1` and `child2` widgets that appear within `parent`. Notice that as the position of `parent` changes, the positions of `child1` and `child2` relative to `parent` are preserved.

I have looked extensively into ways to make this work but have come up empty handed. If there is no simple solution, does anyone have ideas on where to start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a `QHBoxLayout` into the yellow widget, call its `addSpacing` method and then add the green widget into it.

Comment: @jfaccioni Thanks for your response. I'm more concerned with creating a green widget such that it contains the blue and magenta "sub-widgets" that move with it. If the green widget is 400x400 pixels large, then I want to be able to add a subwidget at 100x100 pixels relative to the top-left of the green widget (that stays at this position when the green widget changes position)

Comment: Use layouts - place a type of `QLayout` (there are a bunch to choose from) in the green widget, then place the blue/magenta widgets into the layout. The widgets will be automatically distributed inside the layout. There are many tutorials online explaining how to use layouts in Qt.

Comment: @jfaccioni I need for the positioning of these "subwidgets" to be precise. Is it a reasonable idea to create a QGridLayout with 100+ rows and columns so I can define the position and dimensions of the subwidgets to a high degree?

Comment: Forgetting about the yellow widget fr the time being, do you know how to position the blue and purple widgets on the green parent widget using e.g. [`QWidget::setGeometry`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setGeometry-1)?

Comment: @G.M. I am vaguely familiar with .setGeometry, but I thought this only set the widget's position relative to the window. How would I use .setGeometry to align the widgets with the parent widget's position?

Comment: Re. `"How would I use .setGeometry to align the widgets with the parent widget's position?"`: as per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) that's *exactly* what `setGeometry` does: `"This property holds the geometry of the widget relative to its parent and excluding the window frame"`.

Comment: @G.M. OK, I see now. I thought that the parent of a QWidget had to be a layout and vice versa. I'm really struggling with how to create a widget and then set its parent to be another widget in order for setGeometry to work within the context of the parent widget's position. Looking through the documentation I can't see a function or constructor argument that lets me make a widgets parent another widget.

Comment: Sorry, but you *really* need to read the documentation.  The [first constructor documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget) accepts a `parent` parameter and there's also a member function named [`setParent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent).

Comment: @G.M. I guess this is a lesson in thoroughly reading documentation. Thanks so much for your patience

Comment: @ColinDavis using the parent argument in the constructor is the standard procedure. You can also use `widget.setParent(parent)`, but you have to remember in *both* cases that if the parent is *already* visible, you must explicitly call `show()` or `setVisible(True)` on the child after creating it *or* after setting its [new] parent. This is also valid whenever you want to "unparent" a widget (for instance, make it a top level widget): even after calling `setParent(None)` you must still set it visible again.

Comment: @musicamante Okay, thanks. So to make sure I'm getting it right, ```show()``` will make the widget and all children widgets visible, but if a child widget is added after ```show()``` has already been called, it won't be visible by default?

Comment: @ColinDavis precisely. ***Unless*** the widget is then added to a layout of a widget that is already visible: adding a widget to a layout causes (possible) reparenting, and standard Qt layout managers "know" that, so they automatically show the *new* child if the layout is set for an already visible widget. The basic concept is that making a widget visible will make visible all the children (unless `hide()` or `setVisible(False)` have been explicitly called on them) that exist at the moment in which the parent visibility has been set, not afterwards.